# Error messages "VBoxGuest_RTLogBackdoorPrintf" and "RTAssertShouldPanic" when updating a Linux host with VirtualBox installed

Tags: linux

[image: An update process ...]

This has been noticed on the Linux host updates, where the virtualbox has been installed. Notice "VBoxGuest_RTLogBackdoorPrintf", "RTAssertShouldPanic" and more. What is this process please?

Comment: This is not a security question. Voting to migrate.

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/inaddy/wily/blob/d15bd6cdbb1c2080fb1fca0035e5af1994f4d14f/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/generic/RTAssertShouldPanic-generic.c) and [this](https://github.com/inaddy/wily/blob/d15bd6cdbb1c2080fb1fca0035e5af1994f4d14f/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/VBox/logbackdoor.c).

Comment: Also, this is not "the" Linux with VM question. There are millions of possible "Linux with VM" questions. Please try to find descriptive question titles.